# Adding a column based on the dictionary for one of the columns in the dataset but getting NaN

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to add a column in a dataset, based on a dictionary which is applied to one of the columns in the dataset. But after trying the code below, I am getting NaN in the new column even though, values are not missing from the column on which the dictionary is based on.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
val_dict = {'1':'8','2':'5','3':'3','4':'2'}
df['val2'] = df['val'].map(val_dict)
df
```

The output I am getting is

val  val2

[image]

Comment: u didnt share ur data, so we cant really test. also, are the data u r trying to replace integers or strings?

Comment: Add the output of `df.dtypes` to your question please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your `df`, i assume the column `val` contains interger value. But the dictionary which you presented above contain the keys as `str`.

So change the dict keys from str to int. (`i.e val_dict = {1:'8',2:'5',3:'3',4:'2'})`

E.g : 1 (Shows Error)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'val' : [1,2,2,1,2,3,3,4]})
val_dict = {'1':'8','2':'5','3':'3','4':'2'}
df['val_2'] = df['val'].map(val_dict)
print(df)

       val  val_2
  0     1   NaN
  1     2   NaN
  2     2   NaN
  3     1   NaN
  4     2   NaN
  5     3   NaN
  6     3   NaN
  7     4   NaN
```

E.g : 2 (Corrected dict results)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'val' : [1,2,2,1,2,3,3,4]})
val_dict = {1:'8',2:'5',3:'3',4:'2'}
df['val_2'] = df['val'].map(val_dict)
print(df)

   val  val_2
0     1     8
1     2     5
2     2     5
3     1     8
4     2     5
5     3     3
6     3     3
7     4     2
```